# Reduce multiple whitespaces to a single space in KDB+/Q

Tags: kdb, q-lang

To get from `"a       b"` to `"a b"`

```
ssr["a         b";"[ ]+";" "]
```

doesn't seem to work. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following which treats each repeating space as a pair, 
then using over, 'replaces' these with a single space.

```
q)x:"This         is    a    test"

q)(" "sv"  "vs)/[x]

"This is a test"
```

Comment: Pretty neat! Thanks!  However, is it not possible to use regex in Q? I just can't get this to work and I have potentially more complicated rules. Thank you again.

Comment: You may need to import an external library as q only supports basic operations  ( *,? and [] ) 

Have a look at   http://q.o.potam.us/?p=pcre  &  http://thesweeheng.wordpress.com/2008/07/14/regular-expressions-for-q/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this more efficiently then using `vs` and `sv`. Using the adverb [each-prior `':`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-prior)

```
{x where not(and':)null x}"This         is    a    test"
"This is a test"
```

Alternative you can using `ssr` with the adverb over `/` in order to continuously remove blocks of two spaces:

```
ssr[;"  ";" "]/["This         is    a    test"]
"This is a test"
```

The example you provided fails due to the limited regex options available, using `+` in this sequence `"[ ]+"` is an example of an operation that is not supported. You can read more about [regex in q](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/regex/#regex-in-q) on the kx wiki.